# Invoke function with function name passed as string

Tags: javascript

How to make the alert called for the below snippet?

```
function a(fun) {
    fun.call(null);
}

function x() {
    alert("function called");
}

a("x");
```

Please make sure that editing is to be allowed only for

```
function a(fun) {
    fun.call(null);
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Why do you want to? Just pass the function instead of its name.

Comment: @torazaburo There can be applications actually. For example jQuery plugins pass methods names to invoke. However they don't use global functions of course.

Answer (score 0):

Not many options here. First of all in global window context you can do this:

```
function a(fun) {
    this[fun].call(null); // window[fun].call(null);
}
```

If your functions are in different context above will not work. More flixible approach is to declare methods on the object:

```
function a(fun) {
    obj[fun].call(null);
}

var obj = {
    x: function() {
        alert("function called");
    }
};

a("x");
```

Comment: Right, so doesn't my functions all belong to the global scope which is the window? If yes, why isn't it working.

Comment: No, not all of them are available in global scope. It depends on how you define your function. For example function inside of other function will not be in global scope.

Comment: I was telling about the functions i have defined. all are in global scope, then why it is not working

Comment: Are you sure they are in global scope? `window['functionName']()` works?

Comment: So whats the scope they are in? Is there a name to this scope?

Comment: I can't see your full code so I can't tell. Probably you declare your functions in anonymous IIFE `(function() {})()`.

Comment: What you see is the full code

Answer (score 0):

I think if you like eval then you can do like

```
function a(fun) {
    eval(fun + "()");
}
```

but I still suggest that you should do like this. It is used in callback functionality everywhere in many js library.

```
   function a(fun) {      
    fun();
}

function x() {
    alert("function called");
}

a(x);
```