# What is the scope of this JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

What is the scope for below function, since invoking it using window scope is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function a() {
        alert("function called from global scope");
    }

    // this alerts
    a(); //This is global scope?

    // this doesn't alert
    window["a"]();  //This is also global scope?
});
```

And also let me know how to find the scope of a function, object, or variable?

Comment: a is a private variable (of type function) to the ready callback shown

Comment: the only thing that has scope are functions. functions have the scope of themselves and any outer functions. window is the end of the line.

Comment: The scope of this function is `document` object. `document !== window` so you can't use `window["a"]` of course.

Comment: Related question of what OP is trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456700/invoke-function-with-function-name-passed-as-string

Comment: @dfsq - Then why does not document["a"](); work? or is there a different syntax.

Comment: Because when you define a function in the scope, it doesn't mean that this function becomes a property of the scope object. It's only true for global scope `window`. So you can't access scope function with `this[funcName]` in general.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript has function level scope.** So let's go through the code. You define two functions in the code. The first one is a no-name function that is passed as a callback to `$(document).ready`. Let's call it *callback function*. `a` is defined inside of this callback function and is therefore in local scope. So `a` can only be referred to from inside of the callback function.

You invoke `a` after defining it and see the alert. Then you try to get the reference to `a` from the global object (**everything that is defined globally goes into `window`** in the browser). Since `a` isn't defined globally, you cannot retrieve it from `window`. Actually you retrieve `null` and you see `TypeError: window.a is not a function` on the console when trying to invoke it with `()`.